# Reaction that will produce a silica coating (glaze)

Tags: phase, ceramics

The normal way to create a coating of pure silicon dioxide glaze is to coat the object to be glazed in a slurry of silica particles and then put it in a kiln.

However, if I have an object that is too large to fit in a kiln, then there is a problem.

I am wondering if there is a reaction of some kind that will produce a glaze of pure silica. The idea is that I could coat the object with the reactants, ignite them, and then when the reaction is over the object will be coated with fused silica. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: have you hear of [TEOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraethyl_orthosilicate)?

Comment: This is done in the semiconductor industry using silane, see the Wikipedia article on epitaxy  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitaxy